# Creating sequential Purchase Order Numbers

Tags: microsoft-excel

In Office365 Excel I thought to use the text and row function, e.g.:

```
=text(Row(A1),"000-001")
```

but I want to add CMS to the start of the number range and it will only return `#value`.

I actually want the number format to start at CMS10000 excel.

Answer (score 0):

### Pad the serial number with zeros.

[There are plenty of ways to do it](https://exceljet.net/formula/pad-a-number-with-zeros), like using number-formatting. Here is an easier one.

```
=RIGHT("0000"&ROW(),4)
```

### Use the concatenate command.

```
="CMS1"&RIGHT("0000"&ROW(),4)
```

Note that this will get totally disrupted if you ever add or delete a row from your spreadsheet, and your records will be inaccurate. So:

### Paste as Values.

You could use a "number generator" column with the above formula, and **paste: special: as values** to copy the number into a separate column that won't change.

You can hide the "number generator" column, or move it out of the printable area of the spreadsheet, if you need to.